# MS Access 2010 - When running a report, field shows IDs instead of values

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

I'm running a report off of a query to create room signs showing people in that room.  The query shows the actual room number, but when I create the report from the query, the ID number for the room is shown instead.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you use look-up fields in your table? If so, see http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Comment: Yes lookup fields were used.  I managed to find an odd fix to this by just hitting the report button rather than using the wizard.  I'm not sure how or why that worked, but it did.